# parsing json in an unordered list

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, pagination

i'm parsing a json file in an unordered list.
the problem is that i need to paginate the results  in "ul" containing only 3 items.
so i want to close the ul after 3 results and then reopen it.

here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('/it_IT/eni_nel_mondo/components/menu/comunicati.json', function(data) {

          var list = [];

          $.each(data.items, function(i, c) {
            list.push('<li><a href="#"><div class="title"><div class="data"><span class="number">'+c.day+'</span><span class="month">'+c.month+'</span></div><h4>'+c.title+'</h4></div><p>'+c.abstract+'</p></a></li>');
          });

          $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'results',
            html: list.join('')
          }).appendTo('.wrap .items');
        });
```

any help?

i resolved like this:

```
$.getJSON('/it_IT/eni_nel_mondo/components/menu/comunicati.json', function (data) {
        var list = [];
        var counter = 0;
        $.each(data.items, function (i, c) {
            counter++;
            list.push('<li><a href="#"><div class="title"><div class="data"><span class="number">' + c.day + '</span><span class="month">' + c.month + '</span></div><h4>' + c.title + '</h4></div><p>' + c.abstract + '</p></a></li>');
            if (counter != 0 && counter % 3 == 0) {
                $('<ul/>', {
                    'class': 'results',
                    html: list.join('')
                }).appendTo('.wrap .items');
                list = [];
            }
        });
        if (counter % 3 != 0 && list.length > 0) {
            $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'results',
                html: list.join('')
            }).appendTo('.wrap .items')
        }
```

i hope this could be useful to someone.
thnx to  Aaron Ray  for the response, i've seen the last one when my work was already done.

Comment: So to clarify you want to paginate the ul's without loading a new page correct? In other words, if you grab 30 items you would want to show 3 at a time in a ul and have some sort of next/previous navigation that hides one ul and opens the next ul?

Comment: right!
i already have a plugin managing the uls.
my problem is in the parsing:
it parses 1 only ul while i'd need to close it after 3 items and reopen it..cycling like that

Comment: Is it a custom plugin or is it a plugin you downloaded? Couldn't you just create 1 ul, add all your li's to it, and then hide/show the li's accordingly?

Comment: it's not a custom plugin.
the problem is that the plugin paginate the uls not a "x" number of element

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: no, sorry my mistake, it's not a pagination plugin. it's jquerytools scroller used as pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally worked with that plugin, but if you are confident that you have that working I think the problem is with this part of the code:

```
      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'results',
        html: list.join('')
      }).appendTo('.wrap .items');
```

I am assuming your list array contains all of the data, and it is not just returning 3 items at a time. So list.join('') will dump every single item into the html. You will have to loop through the list and use the modulus operator to create your ul's. Then append them to a container (probably your scrollable items container).

```
var html = "<ul>";
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0 && i > 0) {
        html += "</ul><ul>";
    }
    html += "<li>" + jsonData + "</li">;
}
html += "</ul>";

$("#items").append(html);
```

Comment: thnx Aaron, i solved the problem in another way, i've seen this when i was already done. thnx anyway